# Access Missed Call Log in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Trying to incorporate the missed call log in my windows phone mango application. Is there a way to access the missed call log with the Mango RC or is this still not accessible? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is not available to 3rd party developers.

This is due to the emphasis on the security of user data. (You can get a lot of information about someone from their call history.)